# Issue while generating TFrecord

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to generate tf records file with tensorflow 2.3.0 what got this error

```
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 168, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 158, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 132, in create_tf_example
    classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 101, in class_text_to_int
    return label_map_dict[row_label]
KeyError: 'p'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 168, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 158, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 132, in create_tf_example
    classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 101, in class_text_to_int
    return label_map_dict[row_label]
KeyError: 'p'
```

Can you tell me what is the error
The command which I used for generating tf records are -

```
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

Comment: `IMAGE_PATH + '/train'` should be in some file format example CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Label name are case sensitive...check the Lable Name where you define label Id,,, is same as those orignal label you used in image/dataset.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just include the "p" in the label map with other labels and give it a id then it will work perfectly